# how unzip many zip files found in many subdirectories, all in a certain different directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, unzip

i have a list of zip files, which each zip file in it has also some other zip files, and so on. I need to extract them all, with an ubuntu shell command, and get only the files with the extension *.pdf, into a new empty directory.

This is where i managed to come, i have tried unzip -l "*.zip"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
[How do I recusively unzip nested ZIP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208857/how-do-i-recusively-unzip-nested-zip-files)
comes this one-liner :

```
while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; done
```

This removes all zip files that were done in order to avoid infinite loops.
If you want to conserve these files, take first a backup.

Comment: but how do i only keep files with the extension .pdf?

Comment: The above extracts all files. To extract only zip and pdf replace the command `-exec unzip -- '{}'` by the two commands `-exec unzip -- '{}'  "*.zip" \; -exec unzip -- '{}' "*.pdf`.`